# iOS App Login with Facebook Fail when authenticate with native Facebook app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, facebook-login

I have an iOS native app that supports user login with Facebook.
The app works perfectly fine with my phone:

1. I launch my app and tap on "login with facebook" that is provided by Facebook SDK
2. Facebook SDK opens a web view inside of my app that ask for login with my app (My app is registered in Facebook developer portal)
   [image]
3. I enter my Facebook acc detail and the webveiw therefore closed with a login success result.

However, one of my app customer today sent me a screenshot that shows:

1. He launched my app on his iPhone and tap on "login with facebook" button
2. Instead of showing a web view for login, on his phone the Facebook SDK is showing a button "Log In With the Facebook App"
   [image]
3. Then he tapped on "Open", Facebook native app is launched, following an error message "Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application". My app logo that is registered in Facebook developer portal is not even displayed.
   [image]

To me it looks like a Facebook SDK or Facebook developer portal setting issue as after user tapped on login with Facebook button on my app, it goes into Facebook login workflow and does not interact with my code at all.

Please help.
Alternatively, could you please let me know how to have that "Log In With the Facebook App" on my phone so I can debug at the very least. Right now I have tried with installing Facebook native app on my iPhone without success.

Thank you so much!

Customer's iOS version: 14.3, Facebook iOS SDK version: 9.3.0

By the way, I have implemented the following code in my objective-c, which does not help:

AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
return YES;
}
```

SceneDelegate.m

```
    - (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(NSSet<UIOpenURLContext *> *)URLContexts
{
  UIOpenURLContext *context = URLContexts.allObjects.firstObject;
  [FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance application:UIApplication.sharedApplication
                                               openURL:context.URL
                                     sourceApplication:context.options.sourceApplication
                                            annotation:context.options.annotation];
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the Swift tag for?

Comment: it is iOS SDK which supports both Objective C and Swift. Both solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Same happens to a customer of mine. He has verified the same behavior on an iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS 15.0.2. On my iPhone XR with 15.0.2 I only get the WebView